# discord.py - top 10 specific roles leaderboard

Tags: python, discord.py, leaderboard

What Im trying to do is to have a leaderboard with who has the most roles like:

```
member1 - 10
member2 - 7
member3 - 4
...
```

The main code that works is this:

```py
data = []
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    name, score = member.name, len(member.roles)
    data.append((name,score))
data.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
await ctx.send("Leaderboard")
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(data[:10]):
    await ctx.send(f"{i+1}. {name} - {score}")
```

But I dont want to count the role Member,Admin. So I tried to make the following:

```py
@client.command()
async def top(ctx):
  data = []
  mroles = []
  final = []
  banned = ['Admin','Member']
  for member in ctx.guild.members:
    for roles in member.roles:
      name, score = member.name, roles.name
      mroles.append(score)
  
      for roles in mroles:
        if roles in banned:
          continue
        else:
          final.append(roles)
      
      data.append((name,len(final)))
  data.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
  await ctx.send("Leaderboard")
  for i, (name, score) in enumerate(data[:10]):
      await ctx.send(f"{i+1}. {name} - {score}")
```

But the output is some crazy values and the name of the member x2:

```
 1. testuser - 16671
 2. testuser - 16532
 3. testuser2 - 16393
 4. testuser2 - 16255
```

Any clue? I burn my mind for hours i cant make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `mroles` or `final`. Combined with the nested for loops, this causes it to get crammed with items and increase really fast as you continue.

The names also appear multiple times because your `data.append((name,len(final)))` is running inside of `for roles in member.roles` - meaning they will get another entry in the leaderboard for every role they have.

Here's a fast way to do it:

```py
@client.command()
async def top(ctx):
    data = []
    banned_roles = {'Admin', 'Member'}  # this should be a set, because speed

    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        total_role_count = len(member.roles)
        # Uncomment this line if you don't want the "@everyone" role to be included. Yes, this is an actual role.
        #total_role_count -= 1

        # fast O(n) way to compute # of banned roles
        # it finds the roles that are banned by intersecting the member's roles and the banned roles
        # then take the length of that and subtract it from the total number
        # you could probably also do this using `set.difference`
        role_names = {role.name for role in member.roles}
        banned_count = len(role_names.intersection(banned_roles))

        data.append((member.name, total_role_count - banned_count))

    data.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
    # instead of sending all the messages, send a big message with newlines in it
    # this avoids the ratelimit of 5 messages every 5 seconds
    text = '\n'.join([f"{i+1}. {name} - {score}" for i, (name, score) in enumerate(data[:10])])
    await ctx.send(f'Leaderboard\n\n{text}')
```

Comment: I dont know if i can thank you enough, you saved me ton of time! Thank you a looooooooooooooooot! :D